# The MD5 Hash in Arm Assembly and endianness

Tags: arm, md5, stm32, endianness, cortex-m

I am new to Arm assembly programming. I am attempting to write a function in arm cortex m4 assembly that performs the MD5 Hash algorithm. I am following the wiki page algorithm found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5.

The wikipage declares constants A,B,C,D and the arrays S and K. All the values are shown in little endian.

About little endian:

I have done some research and it seems that in the memory, an entire string is shown **in order**, as if the entire string was in big endian. This is because each character is a byte. The values in the wiki are declared in little endian, so after i declare them, they show up as big endian (normal order) in the memory.

I have done the preprocessing for the MD5 hash. Let me show you what it looks like in memory for the string "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog":

```
 54686520 51756963 6B204272 6F776E20 466F7820 4A756D70 73204F76 65722054 
 6865204C 617A7920 446F672E 80000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00006001
```

So 54=T, 68, =h,... etc...

Now heres where my confusion is.

After the message, a single 1 bit is appended. This is the byte 0x80. After that, the rest of 512 bits are filled with zeros until the last 64 bits, that is where the length of the message goes. So as shown, the message is 0x160 bits long. But the length is in little endian in the memory so it shows up as 6001.

So the length is in little endian in the memory.

But the constants A,B,C,D and array K are declared **initially** in little endian according to the wiki.

So when I view them in the memory, they show up as normal.

So now I am confused! my length is in little endian in the memory, and the constants and K array are in big endian in the memory.

What would be the correct way to view the example in the memory?

Comment: ARM assembly is not for humans. It is for compilers. You actually wasting your time and your assembly probably will be much worse than generated by the C compiler

Comment: But if OP wants to learn Thumb-2 assembly language (and that's a perfectly reasonable thing to want to do) then this would help him to do that...

Comment: @cooperised I rather think it is better to focus on something more important. Learning RISC processor languages is IMO useless. And writing this king of routines in asm is IMO even more useless. In last 5 years (I develop RTOSes and system software) I wrote maybe 100 lines in asm.

Comment: @P__J__ And those 100 lines required an in-depth knowledge of the language, and you had to start somewhere.  Don't criticise the question, answer it!

Comment: FWIW, I also disagree that learning RISC assembly languages is useless.  If anything I'd say learning CISC languages is a bigger waste of time; they tend to be so complex that generating optimised code is a job that only a compiler can hope to perform well unless the programmer is extremely experienced.  At least RISC instruction sets are simple enough to give you a decent shot at writing efficient code by hand.

Comment: @cooperised ARM instruction set is compiler not human optimized. And if it is needed to write couple of lines - it is always something hardware related - never application. But everyone is free to waste own time.

Comment: @P__J__ well it is good that there are many of us out here that 1) bother to try and realize that arm asm is very much humanized 2) we can create and test processors so you have something to use and compilers so that you have languages to use.    Without us there wouldnt be an internet or web or stackoverflow on which you could voice your opinions.

Comment: Anyone who doesnt see the value in assembly language and thus machine code really has no interest in programming in general.  Just users.  Good thing there are programmers out here so that there can be users.

Comment: The programming language used here is not relevant, its a case of understanding some data.  Or more important what program was used to create this data, and use that program to examine the output of the hash.

Comment: @old_timer very brave comment. So  the Java or C# programmers are not programmers. .... interesting idea

Comment: @P__J__ I wasnt the one that started with brave comments.  No machine code no processors, machine code leads to assembly language.  No processors then basically no computers no internet.  No high level languages.  Assembly in general is the easiest language of all of them to understand, its like learning the alphabet before whole words.  of the current processors out there arm dominates in so many ways and its assembly language is one of the easier ones, at least pre aarch64

Comment: @old_timer for the user who does not understands what endianess are should definitely not learn the ARM assembler :)

Comment: any statement that asm is for compilers, is just silly, someone programmed that compiler, so you have to have N people with the programming desire/skills and of those a few that make the compiler, another few that make and test the processor with which we wouldnt have any other languages.

Comment: @old_timer so in your opinion Java or Javascript programmer has to know assembler. i would go futher - shuld know the Inter microcode as well as no microcode - no machine code. For the beginner it is 100% pointles knowledge

Comment: @P__J__ endianess and assembly language programming are two different things. endianness is language independent.  this question appears to be language independent and about data.

Comment: @old_timer you did not answer my question: Is the c# programmer a programmer or user?

Comment: Anyone with basic programming skills has the ability to program in assembly language, maybe not jump from other high level but assembly is so simple then yes.  The have the ability.  The more preaching not to learn leads to less skills overall and worse compilers as we have been seeing lately, which means a high level programmer can get into trouble if they cannot disassemble and determine if their problem is a compiler bug or their code.  or they have to find someone else to do it for them.  Why not just learn it yourself?  why discourage someone from having those skills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programming language and architecture have nothing to do with this.  You are trying to prepare 32 bit values from a string.

```
"The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog."
```

As an ASCII string the bytes looks like this in hex:

```
54 68 65 20 51 75 69 63 6B 20 42 72 6F 77 6E 20 46 6F 78 20 4A 75 6D 70 73 20 4F 76 65 72 20 54 68 65 20 4C 61 7A 79 20 44 6F 67 2E
```

But md5 is about data not strings correct?  More on this in a bit.

You have to be careful with endianness.  Generally folks are talking about byteswapping larger quantities (the address of the byte starts at the top or bottom, big end or little end).  16 or 32 or 64, etc bits.  Initially talking about a 64 bit quantity for the length:

```
0x1122334455667788
```

when looked as a list of bytes in increasing address order, little endian (as far as is generally understood), is

```
88 77 66 55 44 33 22 11
```

so

```
0x0000000000000160
```

would be

```
60 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

And the next question is your string.  Should it start with 0x54686520 or should it start with 0x20656854 or 0x63697551?

I believe from the text in wikipedia

```
The MD5 hash is calculated according to this algorithm. All values are in little-endian.

//Note: All variables are unsigned 32 bit and wrap modulo 2^32 when calculating
```

Then your last (only) chunk should look like

```
0x20656854
0x63697551
0x7242206B
0x206E776F
0x20786F46
0x706D754A
0x764F2073
0x54207265
0x4C206568
0x20797A61
0x2E676F44
0x00000080
0x00000000
0x00000000
0x00000160
0x00000000
```

Using an md5 source routine I found online and using the comes with my Linux distro I got

```
ec60fd67aab1c782cd3f690702b21527
```

As the hash in both cases, and the prepared data for the last/only chunk started with 0x20656854 from this program.  This program also correctly calculated the result for a string on wikipedia.

So from the wikipedia article, which should have handled the 64 bit length a smidge better.  Your data (its not a string) needs to be processed in 32 bit little endian quantities from the 512 bits.

```
54 68 65 20 becomes 0x20656854 0x000000000000160 becomes 0x00000160, 0x00000000.
```

Comment: Ah, so for a 32 bit machine, a 64 bit value such as 0x0000000000000160 appears in memory as 60010000 00000000, and reading the value in registers would be like r0=0x00000160, r1=0x00000000. It's up to the programmer to  know that the number is represented as 64 bits, so r1 in this case is the more significant bits compared to r0.

Comment: well, I wouldnt go so far as to say that.  endianness is not something carved in stone each architecture whether they support only one endianness or more than one chooses their definition.  Which is why at least the wikipedia article is lacking, a proper definition would have more information, it would be complete.  x86 supports 64 bit quantities and at least in the immediate encoding all 8 bytes are swapped.  for ARM I didnt look you can try strd/ldrd to see what you see first reading the pseudo code then experimenting as needed.  and/or use one or more compilers as each compiler can decide

Comment: what their definition is within limits, as you get into the floating point unit it is hopefully consistent with compiler and any other architectural choices.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really true to describe ASCII strings as big-endian.  Endianness applies only to multi-byte values, so ASCII strings have no endianness because they're just arrays of bytes.  If you had an array of 16-bit numbers, for example, then endianness would apply individually to each value in the array but not to the ordering of the elements.

The real answer to your question is that there is no easy way to view 'raw' memory data when it's organised in this way.  Most debuggers have variable watches which can be used to view the contents of memory locations in a type-aware way, which is usually easier; so for example you could tell the watch window that `K` points to a 64-byte string and that `K+56` points to a little-endian 64-bit unsigned integer, and these values would then be interpreted and reported correctly.

More generally it is often difficult to interpret 'raw' memory data in a little-endian system, because knowing which bytes to swap to put values into an order that's easily human-readable relies on knowing how long each value is, and this information is not present at runtime.  It's the downside of the little-endian system, the upside being that casting pointers doesn't change their absolute values because a pointer always points to the least-significant byte no matter how large the data type.

Comment: ARM used two different little endian solutions before armv6 it was word invariant and they switched to byte invariant.  But they also support big endian.

Comment: True.  But almost every implementation I've seen has been little-endian.  Seems to be the standard these days.

Answer (score -1):

If i were to do this, i will find an MD5 library or class, write a simple example to take it text that i want to hash, then ask compiler to generate assembly for the ARM part that i need.

You may consider an mbed [1] or an Arduino [2] version.

[1] https://os.mbed.com/users/hlipka/code/MD5/
[2] https://github.com/tzikis/ArduinoMD5

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question.  Sure, a library is the way to go if you just want an md5 hash - unless the microcontroller has a hardware hash unit, as many of the ST CM4 devices have, for example, in which case you might as well use that and skip the code altogether.  But OP wants help interpreting data in memory, not finding alternative ways to approach the problem.